# Parameters will not be hoisted and will hit temporal dead zone?

Tags: javascript

```js
function bar(x=y, y=2) {
    return [x, y];
}

bar();//uncaught reference: y is not defined
```

I can't understand why the above code will hit exception. If from other languages it make sense because flow of programs are important and we can't reference to y because y is not created yet and it would be resulted in compilation error. However this is `JS`, both x and y should equally be hoisted first and such reference shouldn't throw exception. I would expect the pseudo-code to be similar like below?

```js
x=y

var x;
var y;

console.log(x,y); //undefined undefined (which is fine as no value but instead of throwing exception)
```

**UPDATES:**

```js
function bar() {
    var x = arguments.length >= 1 ? arguments[0] : y;
    {
        var y = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : 2;

        return [x, y];
    }
}

console.log(bar());//[undefined, 2]
```

Comment: Even if `y` was defined that's still a problem in JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue: Can you elaborate more to support your statement?

Comment: `var y = 3; function bar(x=y, y=2) {
    return [x, y];
}

bar();`

Comment: @PHPglue: That's not what I meant, the hoisted part I was expecting was somewhere within the `bar` function scope. The content of `bar` that interpreted by compiler should be something as Barmar's answer that I was expecting

Comment: "However this is JS, both x and y should equally be hoisted first and such reference shouldn't throw exception"??? WRONG

Comment: @PHPglue: It's throwing exception, of course it's somewhere WRONG I get it. But perhaps with some explanation?

Comment: Don't overthink your JavaScript, just chalk it up to a Syntax issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, they're not hoisted like that. It's more like:

```
function bar() {
    let x = arguments.length >= 1 ? arguments[0] : y;
    {
        let y = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : 2;

        return [x, y];
    }
}
```

The scope of each variable default value only includes the variables to the left of it, not the variables to the right.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, can I assume that parameters of functions are `let` by default? But `let` isn't exist in pre ES6 environment. Look at my updates and by changing your code from `let` to `var` will giving me the result im expecting, without throwing exception

Comment: Ok I get that I'm wrong again because preES6 there is no `default parameter`. Thanks a lot to your great answer!

Comment: Even if there was, my answer was just mean as an analogy, not actual implementation.